# Implementing a secret email feature that inserts content into database

Tags: php, mysql, database, email

So I've seen other big companies such as Facebook do this, you have the ability to post via email. So here's what I'm *trying* to do.

1. User signs up and random email "key" generated. This step is done
2. An actual working email is then created based off of the key
3. User can enter a message while sending an email to the key, and the "message" will be stored in a database.

Now here's what I got so far. I'm already generating a unique key that's a-z and 0-9, which is 15 characters long. So it seems fine for a small scale project. This part of the code is done.

Then I have a table called `Keys`, this table has the keys with the email the user *registered* with (The post must be coming from that email, so if the database is compromised it'll still have a bit more security).

Now the real question is how do I *accept* the emails? I know this is done through the mail server, but how do I automatically add emails to the server? It sure would be a pain to add each email by hand. So I just want to create working emails users can send content to, and that content will be inserted into the database. So its pretty much a secret email that can accept emails and pop them into the database. I have seen 0 posts or tutorials about this, so I'm not sure where to kick off at all. Any help would be great. I'd just like to make it clear that I'm not asking for you guys to code it for me or anything in that nature.

Configuration: PostFix, PHP, All on Ubuntu 12.04, Apache

Comment: *"Then I have a table called Keys"* - Sidenote: `keys` in MySQL is a reserved word http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html - just so you know ahead of time. As is `key`.

Comment: Yeah I know about this. I wrapped it in backticks, but thanks for the heads up. I got tons of headaches with reserved words @Fred-ii-

Comment: You're welcome. Just lookin' out for ya ;-)

Comment: done this for VERP - step one, set up the mail server to accept all incoming. 2 pipe that to a php script. generic answers because it depends on your mail server. having a subdomain just for this email is a good idea `post.yourdomain.com` then you send(pipe) anything to `*@post.yourdoman.com` to the script.

Comment: When you say _accept all incoming_, you're referring to something like this [post](http://serverfault.com/questions/49044/simple-postfix-configuration-forward-all-incoming-email-to-single-address)? Then pass all the emails to PHP, and essentially insert from there? Or maybe even something like [this](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-setup-postfix-catch-all-email-accounts/)? Also thanks for really helping me out on here, I'm starting to get an idea of how it might work. @d

Comment: you can use [this](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-setup-postfix-catch-all-email-accounts/) or if you having a hosting account you can setup default email to catch all the emails in the control panel

Comment: @Dagon couldn't full tag you in the other comment, so here ^^

Comment: yes and yes ... particulars depends on hosting and mail server, so i cant really be specific.

Comment: Then I'd do something like [this](http://jaysonrowe.blogspot.com/2012/03/parsing-e-mail-with-php.html) to get the content? @ArunKumar

Comment: Yes and parsing key using To: email id depending on the key you can insert into the DB

Comment: Can you Provide the details of your environment it would be helpful. like what Mail server are you using , Control Panel etc. so you can configure PostFix to pipe the emails to a php script rite

Comment: I'll do so right now @Arun

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **PostFix Solution**

First Setup the postfix to pipe all the emails to a script there are so many tutorials covering that. I can't give you the complete steps to set up the postfix piping check the provided url for more information on this.

**[1. Postfix Piping Incoming Mail](http://www.serveridol.com/2011/04/26/postfix-piping-all-mails-to-custom-script/)**

**[2. Postfix Piping Incoming mail](https://serverfault.com/questions/258469/how-to-configure-postfix-to-pipe-all-incoming-email-to-a-script)**

You can use the below script which will parse the emails handed by postfix. You will get From, To, Subject, Message etc you can customize the script

> Note: this is not complete its rather a copy paste version just want to show the concept. There are so many libraries to parse emails
>   .

```
#!/usr/bin/php -q
<?php
//this code will read the piped mail from the postfix 
$fd = fopen("php://stdin", "r");
$email_content = "";
while (!feof($fd)) {
 $email_content .= fread($fd, 1024);
}
fclose($fd); 

//split the string into array of strings, each of the string represents a single line, received
$lines = explode("\n", $email_content);

// initialize variable which will assigned later on
$from = "";
$subject = "";
$headers = "";
$message = "";
$is_header= true;

//loop through each line
for ($i=0; $i < count($lines); $i++) {
    if ($is_header) {
        // hear information. instead of main message body, all other information are here.
        $headers .= $lines[$i]."\n";         

        if (preg_match("/^Subject: (.*)/", $lines[$i], $matches)) {
            $subject = $matches[1];
        }
        //Split sender information portion
        if (preg_match("/^From: (.*)/", $lines[$i], $matches)) {
            $from = $matches[1];
        }
        //Split To information portion
        if (preg_match("/^To: (.*)/", $lines[$i], $matches)) {          
            preg_match('/<(.*?)>/s', $matches[1], $to);
            $key = $to[1];
        }
    } else {
    // content/main message body information
        $message .= $lines[$i]."\n";
    }
    if (trim($lines[$i])=="") {
        // empty line, header section has ended
        $is_header = false;
    }
}


print $key;
```

Once you have the key you can use that to validate. You can Insert them into database and notify related users or post topics etc.

> **Mandrill solution**

use this link to to configure [mandrill](http://help.mandrill.com/entries/21699367-Inbound-Email-Processing-Overview) to a url example example.com/parse.php once this is configured you use below php script to insert body of the email to your databse

```
$mails = json_decode($_POST['mandrill_events']);
foreach ($mails as $mail) {
   $stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO mail (text) VALUES (:mail)");
   $stmt->bindValue(':mail', $mail->msg->text);
   $stmt->execute();
}
```

the above script is only taking email body. you can use [Mandrill Help](http://help.mandrill.com/entries/22092308-What-is-the-format-of-inbound-email-webhooks-) to know more options like from_email, to, subject etc

Comment: I'm using Postfix. Running on Ubuntu 12.04 which is using Apace. This enough? Also no cpanel

Comment: @Idris is this what you are looking for. Or you want more information on specific topic?

Comment: So I pipe the emails. Then call that index.php for example? What else after that?

Comment: @idris You want to create a post using the email message rite?

Comment: Well yeah. Someone sends an email. Then it automatically sends the content to a database.

Comment: @idris See the above script you will get $key use that to search db if the key exists. Post $message and other fields to the database

Comment: Yeah, but in order for the script to execute I'd have to load it up every time?

Comment: No it will be executed by the postfix with the message as input

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58070/discussion-between-arun-kumar-and-idris).

Answer (score -1):

Do you mind using an external service?

If not, you could try Mandrill (it's from Mailchimp).

It allows you to call webhook for inbound emails, which are configured using routes. All you need to do is point the MX domain to their servers. It's free up to 12k emails / day.

http://help.mandrill.com/categories/20102127-Inbound-Email-Processing

Comment: I don't really mind working with an external server, but now how would I do the rest of the configuration?

Comment: 1. Create an account & login
2. Enable inbound email in Mandrill : you will need to configure your MX domain to point to Mandrill
3. Add a webhook in Mandrill
4. The URL you configured will be called by Mandrill when an email matching the route you configured is received

Comment: Yes I understand. But what about parsing emails?

Comment: Mandrill does all the work for you, you get all you need in the POST array : http://help.mandrill.com/entries/22092308-What-is-the-format-of-inbound-email-webhooks-

Comment: Maybe extending the post with that info would be nice.